# Cast a generic ArrayList element into a primitive type (long)

Tags: java

I would like to write a method which confronts an element of a generic ArrayList with a long number. I know that the array contains only Long values, so I don’t need to check this. This is my method:

```
searchSum(ArrayList <T> array, long n);
```

The confrontation I need to do is:

```
array.get(index)==n
```

Comment: If it only contains `Long`s, change `ArrayList<T>` to `ArrayList<Long>`

Comment: You also can't use `==` to compare `Long` values.

Comment: @Kayaman but he's comparing a `Long` to a `long`, so I believe it would be unboxed.

Comment: What is the expected  answer? Do you want to find that element? Or to sum all elements with that value or what?

Comment: @VeselinDavidov How do I can cast my instance of Array List of Longs into a primitive long

Comment: @Eran yes, it should be "shouldn't", not "can't". It's not a good habit to get used to doing object/primitive comparisons with `==`, even if they are autounboxed.

Comment: You cannot cast the list to primitive types because the list contains objects not primitive. But you still need that in order to achieve something right?

Comment: @Eran And how can I compare a Long element with a long one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot cast list to primitives. Java list contains Objects and the primitives are not objects. But depending on what you want to do I am pretty sure there is an easy way to achieve it. Unfortunately from your question I can hardly understand what is the goal.

If you want to find if the list contains an element you can use:

`array.indexOf(new Long(n));` and it will tell you the index of the first ocurance of the element.

If you just want to see if it is there you can use `array.contains(new Long(n));`

If
 you want to sum all elements (since your method is called searchSum) you can do:

```
searchSum(ArrayList <T> array, long n){
for (Long element: array){
   if(Long.valueOf(n).equals(element)){
        .... do something here...
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: I need to sum two elements from the ArrayList and check in the Sum equals the long element I pass as parameter.

Comment: `Long.valueOf(n)` is better than `new Long(n)` , according to the javadoc: _If a new Long instance is not required, this method should generally be used in preference to the constructor Long(long)_

Comment: Which two elements you need to sum? To find if the list contains a sum or what?

Comment: Thanks. valueOf is indeed better ;)

Comment: `new Long()` and other wrappers constructors have been deprecated since `Java-9`

Comment: So, Long.valueOf(array.get(index))==element is correct?

Comment: @JimBelushi not `==` but `Long.valueOf(array.get(index)).equals(element)` should do the trick

Comment: For longs even == is correct but you should get into the habbit of using equals for objects ;)